# Coded UI Cross browser firefox does not work

Tags: c#, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I have an issue with codedUI. I have recorded step in Internet explorer. Step are lunching a website, login to the website and more... I tehn installed CodedUITestCrossBrowser following the instruction i could find http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx

I run the test in each browser. for IE and chrome the test work but with Firefox, it will not lunch the URL. The page open but nothing is done. My test will then give me this error.

> Test method QaAutomatisation.Reseller.DristributorCreation threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: Failed to start up socket within 45000
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.Utility.MapAndReThrow(Exception exception)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.Launch(Uri uri)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserFactory.Launch(Uri uri)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.LaunchPrivate(Uri uri)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.<>c_*DisplayClass3d.b*_3c()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod(Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.Launch(Uri uri)
>      at QaAutomatisation.UINewTabWindowsInterneWindow.LaunchUrl(Uri url) in UIMap.Designer.cs: line 425
>      at QaAutomatisation.UIMap.LoginAdminCP() in UIMap.Designer.cs: line 71
>      at QaAutomatisation.Reseller.DristributorCreation() in Reseller.cs: line 44

```
        //The code that have been generated is 
        // Go to web page 'http://master.controlpanel3.test.mail.dev.sherweb.com/' using new browser instance
        this.UINewTabWindowsInterneWindow.LaunchUrl(new System.Uri(this.LoginAdminCPParams.UINewTabWindowsInterneWindowUrl));

        // Type 'xyz' in 'Username' text box
        uIUsernameEdit.Text = this.LoginAdminCPParams.UIUsernameEditText;

         public void LaunchUrl(System.Uri url)
    {
        this.CopyFrom(BrowserWindow.Launch(url));
    }
```

I am using visual studio premium 2012 with update 2, Selenium 2.32.1 and the crossbrowser extension.

Hope you have everything

Thanks again for the help !!

Comment: try on firefox 21-20 and 19. same results.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I had an instance of Firefox running prior to my test executing. Make sure all of your Firefox browser windows are closed before running your coded UI test in Firefox.